# Matlab for loop that manipulates a list?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I am new to Matlab so I apologize for relatively easy questions.

I have:

```
for i=0:10
    values(:,1) = (2.*i-20)*5.;
end
```

I want the script to produce a vector of 11 values that have been changed by the `(2.*i-20)*5`. for each `i`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this:

```
for i=0:10
    values(i+1,1) = (2.*i-20)*5.; %you can also write -> values(i)
end
```

More general way to fill an array in a `for` loop when your loop variable doesn't go from `1` to the desired value:

```
count=0;
for i=0:10
    count=count+1;
    values(count,1) = (2.*i-20)*5.;
end
```

But wait, this is not at all a good way of programming in MATLAB. You should do such operations as follows:

```
i=0:10;
values=(2.*i-20)*5.;
```

The above solution is called a vectorized solution.

Comment: @ronica Please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark on the left hand side. By doing so, it will get off the unanswered list.